# Big blanks in document, why?

Tags: spacing

The following code uses a command \unit which is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\pagebreak \section{Unit: #1}}
```

A unit is therefore just a section that starts on a new page.

```
\unit{How to use a Breadboard: Best Practices}
A breadboard, or solderless breadboard, is a way to quickly connect ...
```

The title of the unit does appear at the top of the page, then:

[image]

Why is there the big gap before the text?  The same thing happens for an itemized list.  We want the text to be at the top, but if there is extra space on the page LaTeX moves the bullet list down to equally space them.

Comment: Use \newpage instead of \pagebreak.

Comment: You may have to issue `\raggedbottom` in your preamble.

Comment: presumably whatever is on the next page will not fit on this, and you have specified `\flushbottom` so tex has no other way to align the bottom baseline but to stretch the space.

Comment: \raggedbottom is the answer!